# Spark Structured Streaming mapGroupWithState output to parquet

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I have a Spark Structured Streaming application which doing event merges with **mapGroupWithState**.  It works perfect with **console** sink, but in production I need to write data in parquet format, but I'm confusing, because **mapGroupWithState** requires **Update** mode and **parquet** output requires **Append** mode. Is there any solution here ? Or can we use **foreach** sink someway for this case.

```
val query: Dataset[BidData] = bidStream
    .groupByKey(_.auction_id)
    .mapGroupsWithState(GroupStateTimeout.ProcessingTimeTimeout())(updateBidState)
    .flatMap(b => b)

query.writeStream
    .outputMode(OutputMode.Update())
    .format("parquet")
    .option("path", appConfig.s3Output)
    .option("checkpointLocation", appConfig.checkpoint)
```

Comment: How do you imagine stored this data in parquet file? as far as I understand, there will be several states saved in parquet, how are you going to consume this data? Do you need historical state changes? If so, I'd suggest sink this stream to Kafka etc. and have another stream from Kafka to parquet in Append mode.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use flatMapGroupsWithState with append mode (mapGroupWithState is a special case of flatMapGroupsWithState).

But if you do so, your parquet file will contain all the historical bid states within it. If you need to get the last bid state you will have to write queries (I assume you will use SparkSQL or Hive) to return the last bid state.

Refer:
https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/spark-structured-streaming/spark-sql-streaming-KeyValueGroupedDataset-flatMapGroupsWithState.html